# What's the difference between "image[:, :, 1]" and "cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)"?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, ocr

Giving this image:

[image: Colored pencils]

If we do `image[:, :, 1]`, we see:

[image: Greyscale one]

While doing `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`:

[image: Greyscale two]

They are slightly different, but just slightly.

Is there any specific reason for using the array accessing `[:, :, 1]` instead of the `cv2.cvtColor()` call?

Actually, what does `[:, :, 1]` exactly do? Can you explain in a few words I better understand?

My final purpose is to extract text from some images. Should I stick to some of the two explained methods? Or should they be quite the same?

Comment: `[:, :, 1]` is the green channel, while `cv2.cvtColor()` call one is the grayscale image. Those are two different things.

Comment: To see the difference, you can do a quick check : `a = np.zeros((400,400,3),dtype=np.uint8);
a[...,1] = 255;
cv2.imwrite('green.png',a);
cv2.imwrite('gray.png',cv2.cvtColor(a, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))` and then check out those 2 images.

Comment: Thanks @Divakar for this piece, simple but helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you loaded the image with **OpenCV**, `image[:,:,0]` will be the Blue channel, `image[:,:,1]` will be the Green channel and `image[:,:,2]` will be the Red channel. I am saying **OpenCV** uses `BGR` ordering.

If you opened the image with **PIL/Pillow** or almost any other module, `image[:,:,0]` will be the Red channel, `image[:,:,1]` will be the Green channel and `image[:,:,2]` will be the Blue channel. I am saying the rest of the world uses `RGB` ordering.

Now, look at the red pencil, it will be bright white in the Red channel because there is lots of red in it. Look at the blue pencil, it will be bright white in the Blue channel. Look at the green pencil, it will be bright white in the Green channel.

If you convert to greyscale, the Red, Green and Blue channels are **mixed** in certain percentages rather than being selected exclusively in their entirety:

```
grey = 0.30*R + 0.59*G + 0.11*B
```

So, if you use `cvtColor(...,BGR2GRAY)` the greens will show up lightest (because they have a bigger weighting), then the reds, and the blues will be darkest.

Comment: Great answer @Mark Setchell. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`[:, :, 1]` is a representation of Red Green Blue, so it's just another way of saying `rgb(0, 0, 1)`.
`cv2.cvtColor()` on the other hand is also a change of the colorspaces, but with `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` as the parameter, you actually use grayscales instead.

Comment: Thanks @Tjofoed! Sorry for my ignorance on it, but, why don't I see the output of `image[:, :, 1]` kinda green? In fact, testing with the three channels, i always see the same grey output. Am I doing some mistake? Is it some limitation on source image?

Comment: @Afialapis It isn't supposed to be "green image". It's supposed to show you the intensities of green channel.

Comment: No need to apologize!
You can set rgb from 0-255, and by setting it to 1, you only get 1/255 of the chosen color, where 0 is black and 255 is red/green/blue.
Depending on your sight, you'll have to enter a higher number in order to see the actual color. Hope it makes sense!